# sub folders access to multiple groups

Tags: linux, permissions

I Have a shared directory Department, it has 3 sub directories department wise Account, Sales, Presales and each sub directory have there department employees directory in the same like acc1, acc2, acc3 / sale1, sales2 / ps1, ps2, ps3, ps4

how each employees have a username password to access there directory only without viewing any other directory.

the same thing I made in windows server.

how I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

First, have each employee belong to the department group, i.e. acc1 belongs to Account and ps3 belongs to Presales. 
Then, on department level, have each subdirectory under Department have its group ID equal to the respective department group, with group level read+execute access and revoke all access from others, so it looks like this when you do `ls -la Departments`:

```
drwxr-x---  5 root Account  4096 Jul 25 08:43 Account
drwxr-x---  6 root Presales 4096 Jul 25 08:44 Presales
drwxr-x---  4 root Sales    4096 Jul 25 08:44 Sales
```

Then, have each employee directory user ID & group ID be the user, have the user have full access to the directory, and revoke all access from group & others, for example for Account:

```
drwx------ 2 acc1 acc1 4096 Jul 25 08:43 acc1
drwx------ 2 acc2 acc2 4096 Jul 25 08:43 acc2
drwx------ 2 acc3 acc3 4096 Jul 25 08:43 acc3
```

`chown`, `chgrp` and `chmod` are your friends if you do this on command line. See e.g. http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml for details on their usage.

---

This method works as far as the permissions/memberships can be defined hierarchically and uniformly, i.e. there is no need to mix different kinds and/or levels of permissions on a certain level (e.g. some individual users have read-write access but users only belonging to a group have just read-only access) - for those cases ACLs are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set up FACLS for these directories. It would be the cleanest, best, and preferred method if you need more complicated access control lists.

use man pages for:

## man getfacl

## man setfacl

usage is going to be something like this:

## setfacl -m d:g:"groupname":rwx /path/to/desired/directory

## setfacl -m g:"groupname":rwx /path/to/desired/directory

The first line sets up the rule to be applied automatically to newly created files/folders in the directory.
The second applies to the same upper-level directory where these are being applied, but this gives access to that directory as it already exists.

***NOTE: the quotes around groupname indicate you should fill in the name of the group in your command. do not use the actual quotes when executing the command, you want the group name in there without quotes.